# No puedo validar un formulario con Javascript, y enviar la informacion con php, pero me llegan los mensajes en blanco al correo

Tags: javascript, php, backend

Estoy desarrollando una pagina web, donde necesito crear un formulario de contacto en el cual los usuarios puedan contactarme enviandome un mensaje directamente al correo. Es decir, es un formulario de contact.

La validacion de los inputs esta hecha con Javascript, pero al momento de usar php para enviarlos a mi correo, los mensajes me llegan en blanco. No se si se deba a alguna incompatibilidad entre la validacion de Javascript y la validacion de php, o si tenga que primero almacenar la informacion en el localstorage. Alguna sugerencia???

PD: La web ya esta alojada en un webhost.

Comment: Bienvenido Víctor, al parecer ya hiciste el recorrido por la página, pero sería bueno que leas [ask] y así puedas mejorar tu pregunta. Luego de leerlo notarás que si no lo modificas podrían darte puntos negativos o reportes...

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez esto te ayude...

codigo de formulario en el **Front**:

```
<form method="post" name="contact_form"
  action="contacto.php">
  Your Name:
  <input type="text" name="name">

  Email Address:
  <input type="text" name="email">

  Message:
  <textarea name="message"></textarea>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

codigo para recibir la data en el **Back** de php

```
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$to = 'tucorreo@website.com'

$email_subject = "El contacto que envio: $name";

$email_body = "Has recibido un nuevo mensaje. ".

" Aqui los detalles:\n Nombre: $name \n ".

"Correo: $email_address\n Mensaje\n $message";

$headers = "From: $myemail\n";

$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    
echo "mensaje enviado";
```

recuerda que es la libreria de mail de php https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php